# How to implement UDP client and send data in Swift on iPhone?

Tags: ios, sockets, swift, udp

I want to develop UDP client and send data in Swift.

I have reference the following link:

[Swift: Receive UDP with GCDAsyncUdpSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790129/swift-receive-udp-with-gcdasyncudpsocket)

[Retrieving a string from a UDP server message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25824480/retrieving-a-string-from-a-udp-server-message)

[Swift UDP Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876189/swift-udp-connection)

But I could not find a good way to implement `UDP` in `Swift`.

Can someone teach me **How to implement UDP client and send data in Swift  on iPhone?**

Comment: Please clarify how your question is different to the [Swift UDP Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876189/swift-udp-connection) one? It shows how to send data via UDP in Swift?

Comment: I can not understand the answer you post in [Swift UDP Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876189/swift-udp-connection). Where can I put the data and IP address in the code?

Comment: This is how I got UDP to work in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790129/swift-receive-udp-with-gcdasyncudpsocket/26818254#26818254

Answer (score 4):

for me, I used [this](https://github.com/gunterhager/UDPBroadcastConnection), and its usage:

```
broadcastConnection = UDPBroadcastConnection(port: 35602) { [unowned self] (response: (ipAddress: String, port: Int, response: [UInt8])) -> Void in
    print("Received from \(response.ipAddress):\(response.port):\n\n\(response.response)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dupe to [Swift UDP Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876189/swift-udp-connection).

Refactoring the example a little bit:

```
let INADDR_ANY = in_addr(s_addr: 0)

udpSend("Hello World!", address: INADDR_ANY, port: 1337)

func udpSend(textToSend: String, address: in_addr, port: CUnsignedShort) {
  func htons(value: CUnsignedShort) -> CUnsignedShort {
    return (value << 8) + (value >> 8);
  }

  let fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) // DGRAM makes it UDP

  var addr = sockaddr_in(
    sin_len:    __uint8_t(sizeof(sockaddr_in)),
    sin_family: sa_family_t(AF_INET),
    sin_port:   htons(port),
    sin_addr:   address,
    sin_zero:   ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
  )

  textToSend.withCString { cstr -> Void in
    withUnsafePointer(&addr) { ptr -> Void in
      let addrptr = UnsafePointer<sockaddr>(ptr)
      sendto(fd, cstr, strlen(cstr), 0, addrptr, socklen_t(addr.sin_len))
    }
  }

  close(fd)
}
```

If you have the target IP as a string, use inet_pton() to convert it to an in_addr. Like so:

```
var addr = in_addr()
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.1", &buf)
```

Feel free to steal code from over here: [SwiftSockets](https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets/blob/master/SwiftSockets/SocketAddress.swift)

Oh, and if you plan to do any serious network programming, grab this book: [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but if I want to send byte data. I already change the string to the byteArray like the code: var byteArray : `[Byte] = [0x55, 0xAA, 0x01]
        var data = " {\"SN\":\""+DeviceSN_text.text+"\",\"password\":\""+DevicePWD_text.text+"\"}"

        for char in data.utf8{
            byteArray += [char]
        }`

How to change the code ?

Comment: That should be easy for you to adapt. Instead of cstr/strlen just use the byte buffer you already have (and its length).

Comment: Where does it send? The address is.. 0? How would I change this to set a specific ip?

Comment: This is covered in the answer: If you have the target IP as a string, use inet_pton() to convert it to an `in_addr`.

Answer (score 1):

very nice sample! 
My two cents.. fixed for swift 4.2. / Xcode 10,
(I love using 20 lines instead of a bunch of other files.. and Pods.. ).
Added some more returned results.

```
import Foundation

func udpSend(textToSend: String, address: in_addr, port: CUnsignedShort) {


func htons(value: CUnsignedShort) -> CUnsignedShort {
    return (value << 8) + (value >> 8);
}

let fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) // DGRAM makes it UDP

let addr = sockaddr_in(
    sin_len:    __uint8_t(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size),
    sin_family: sa_family_t(AF_INET),
    sin_port:   htons(value: port),
    sin_addr:   address,
    sin_zero:   ( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
)

let sent = textToSend.withCString { cstr -> Int in

    var localCopy = addr

    let sent = withUnsafePointer(to: &localCopy) { pointer -> Int in
        let memory = UnsafeRawPointer(pointer).bindMemory(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1)
        let sent = sendto(fd, cstr, strlen(cstr), 0, memory, socklen_t(addr.sin_len))
        return sent
    }

    return sent
}

close(fd)
```

}

Comment: How can we send image data?

Answer (score 0):

After pretty extensive research coming up with only basic pointers towards GCD's AsyncSocket, and being a pure Swift trained iOS programmer, I looked for something with native Swift socket support.

Thankfully, I found a much simpler alternative to using Async, called SwiftSocket.

The github (https://github.com/xyyc/SwiftSocket) has examples for most sockets, and is ready to use by copying just a few files into a project.

For swift-only devs, I feel its underutilized and will quickly replace Async for non-objective-c apps. Then again I'm pretty new to this stuff so I may be way off :D

Comment: ok, but I cannot understand why "some files" instead of some lines, as above  :)